# It there a way to use the search API call as a means of getting item id by path?

Tags: box-api

I am integrating Box into my app using the Java SDK and I would like to know whether or not there is a good way to use the search API call to get an item id by path.

The app can potentially have 100k + files and I need a reliable way to get the box id of a path (folder or file).

I was considering using a folder traversal as suggested by answers to similar questions, but given the number of files that may need to be traversed I'm worried about hits in performance.

Is using the search API call a good replacement for this?

Is there a way to restrict the query just to the name field of the item?

Is there a way to get only exact matches?

Will this perform potentially worse than doing a folder traversal?

Thanks,

George

Comment: Search will return you multiple results ranked by relevance.  You can't restrict queries to just the name attribute.  The only query params you can pass are limit and offset currently. Depending on your application, search may be the best option or traversing folders/files may give you more exact result(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is using the search API call a good replacement for this?

No, the search API will be sorted by Box's search relevance algorithm and may not map to what you want.

> Is there a way to restrict the query just to the name field of the item?

Not currently.

> Is there a way to get only exact matches?

Not currently.

> Will this perform potentially worse than doing a folder traversal?

Probably, because you aren't guaranteed to get an exact match.